# Visualization of a game that you just played

Tags: brain, memory, psychologist-psychology, dreams, hippocampus

Do you see video of a game you just played before sleeping? It happens to me almost every time I play a XBOX / mobile / even a simple game for more than an hour or two.

After I play a game, when I close my eyes I see videos of the game I just played. Video appears the second I close my eyes and it is impossible to avoid visualizing. However, I can look around (in my visualization) the objects, move and do all the actions I could in the real game.

This doesn't stop there and continues to my dreams in sleep. Sometimes it even continues to next morning. At work, if I just close my eyes for a second or two it appears again. But by end of the day the effect would be gone.

I'm just curious to know if this is common with others or is it a condition ? what is the effect known as ? Any other info I can get? Thanks.

Update: 
Thanks for replying guys. But I do not game too much. :p I do it occasionally like once or twice a month or even less. Although I like gaming I restrict myself from playing it. Coming to Tetris effect, to my understanding I don't think this is Tetris effect. Tetris effect is applying the logic you used in a game in real life. But my case is something different, I visualize it only when I close my eyes. I have observed Tetris effect when I do extensive coding. But that's my job :)

Comment: Hmm. That's strange, it happens to me but not as severe. I guess it's from hours of gaming. I suppose our parents were right haha. When I go to bed, I close my eyes and visualize my character walking around in a game but, I think that's just the brain filling the void literally. Nothing to worry about :)

Comment: You seem to have some advanced version of a Tetris Effect

Comment: This is normal, but indicative of too much gaming.